# Differences between embedded kafka and testcontainers kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have simple spring boot kafka listener.
And i want to test it.

What are drawbacks of testing using embedded kafka VS testing with test containers kafka?
Im familliar with testcontainers, it provides fully dunctional kafka. What are limitations of embedded kafka compared to container?(Concrete examples pls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any limitations at all with the embedded broker.

It was created long before the TestContainers Kafka module.

One benefit is that it can be configured to auto-provision topics used by the tests.

Another benefit is you can easily create a cluster if needed.

Comment: You can easily create a cluster with the embedded broker.

Comment: One drawback is Embedded kafka only allows to create same number of partitions for multiple topics. If I want 2 topics, one having single partition and another having 3 partitions, there's no way to do this in embedded kafka. Please correct me if there's any way.

Comment: You can create topics with any characteristics you need using one of the `EmbeddedKafkaBroker.doWithAdmin()` methods.

Comment: Can one test rebalancing using multiple JVMs ?

See also https://twitter.com/graemerocher/status/1194195068640546816?lang=en

Comment: You can only do that easily with a fixed port, which can cause the CI binding issues described in that tweet. So, no, not really; but you don't need 2 JVMs to test rebalancing, just fire up a second consumer in the same JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Integration testing failure scenarios using `testcontainers` with `toxiproxy`  may not be possible with `embedded-kafka`.

https://chrzaszcz.dev/2020/08/kafka-testing/
[image: code sample]