# Spring Cloud Integration test, embedded kafka vs testcontainers

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, testcontainers

I have a Spring cloud stream application which I need to make an integration test for (to be specific using cucumber). The application communicate with other services using Kafka message broker. From what I know I could make this work using either a kafka testcontainers or using spring provided embedded kafka. But what I don't know is which one would be the best solution so are there anything that the testcontainer could do but embedded can't or the other way around? (use cases or example would be appreciate!)

p.s This integration should be able to run on ci/cd pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

It is called `embedded` for a reason. It really can be only accessed from the process which spawned it. With Testcontainers you really can reuse existing container and have access to it from the other process. But that's probably to exotic.

I guess with properly configured Testcontainers you can reach as much as possible similarities with the prod you'd deploy your solution. The embedded Kafka might be limited in some areas, e.g. SSL configuration or so.

Comment: Thanks Artem! I guess it depends on how deep I want the test to be then. If I just want to confirm the functionality then embedded probably is enough, but if I want to make sure that it will work with the prod's specific setting I should go with containers.

I can't upvote yet but your answer is helpful, thanks again!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855274/differences-between-embedded-kafka-and-testcontainers-kafka/66855973#66855973